# ScrollTop js function lag on first use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing code for when a button is clicked it will animate going to a certain spot on the page.  The problem is the first time I execute the code it is very laggy on the scrollTop animation.  I am using [w3schools code](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll) so I was surprised it was not working.

Here is the code I am using to animate the scrolling:

```
            // Add smooth scrolling to all links
            $("a").on('click', function (event) {

                // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
                if (this.hash !== "") {
                    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Store hash
                    var hash = this.hash;

                    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                    // The optional number (400) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                    }, 500, function () {

                        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                        window.location.hash = hash;
                    });

                } // End if
            });
```

Comment: do you have issue in the w3schools example ?. if no, please share the html also

Comment: w3 works for me @NidhinChandran

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Have you tried a different one?